# Fourier transform of $(1/\sqrt{x}) \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

I struggle with the following: Given the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}$, I want to prove that its fourier transform $\hat{f}\notin L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cup  L^2(\mathbb{R}) \cup C_0(\mathbb{R})$. I can calulate the following (given I didn't miscalculate, I used the transformation $x=t^2$)
$$\hat{f}(\omega) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\omega t^2} \mathrm{d}t$$
Is it possible to evaluate this integral further or can I deduce from this form that the transformed function is not an element in the given spaces? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I am pretty sure that $\hat{f}\in C_0$, since $f$ is integrable. For the other two spaces: What properties of the Fourier transform do you know? Fourier inversion? Plancherel's theorem?

Comment: $C_0$ are the continuous functions with compact support. I don't see how it would follow that $\hat{f}\in C_0$ when $f$ is integrable. I can use whatever is applicable.

Comment: Plancherel's theorem is interesting, however it states something like ($f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^2(\mathbb{R}) \Rightarrow \hat{f} \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$). Isn't that the wrong way to be helpful?

Comment: The way I know Plancherel's theorem, it states that $\widehat{f} \in L^2$ if and only if $f \in L^2$. For $C_0$: I thought this would be the functions with $f(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$. With your definition: Do you know that the Fourier transform of a compactly supported function is analytic?

Comment: Ah I see, since the $f\notin L^2$ for the example above it follows $\hat{f} \notin L^2$. So $L^1 \cup C_0$ remains. For the second thing: I didn't know that, but I can use that for sure. Would that help?

Comment: All right, I found a way to show any real-analytic function cannot have compact support. Still, I don't see how $\hat{f}\notin L^1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the hints that I gave you in the comments:

You don't have $\widehat{f} \in C_0$ (the space of continuous, compactly supported functions), since $f$ has compact support, which implies that $\widehat{f}$ is analytic. Thus, if $\widehat{f}$ had compact support, we would have $\widehat{f} \equiv 0$, and then $f = 0$ (almost everywhere) by Fourier inversion.

Next, you have $f \in L^1 \setminus L^2$, so that Plancherel's theorem implies that $\widehat{f} \notin L^2$ as well.

Finally, if you had $\widehat{f} \in L^1$, then by Fourier inversion you would get $f(x) = \widehat{\widehat{f}}(-x)$ almost everywhere, which implies (why?!) that $f$ is almost everywhere equal to a continuous function. This is impossible (why precisely?).